# Spark Streaming: write source records and calculate aggregates in single pass

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, amazon-kinesis

I am reading from a Kinesis stream:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("data", T.StringType(), True),
        T.StructField("metadata", T.StructType([
            T.StructField("timestamp", T.TimestampType(), True),
            T.StructField("record-type", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("operation", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("partition-key-type", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("partition-key-value", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("schema-name", T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField("table-name", T.StringType(), True)
        ]), True)
    ]
)

kinesis = (
    spark.readStream
        .format("kinesis")
        .option("streamName", "data-platform-aws-dms-poc-dms-sample")
        .option("region", "us-east-1")
        .option("initialPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON")
        .load()
        .selectExpr("partitionKey", "CAST(data AS STRING) AS data", "stream", "shardId", "sequenceNumber", "approximateArrivalTimestamp")
        .withColumn("data", F.from_json("data", schema))
        .selectExpr("partitionKey", "data.data", "data.metadata.*", "stream", "shardId", "sequenceNumber", "approximateArrivalTimestamp")
)
```

And writing the output to Delta Lake:

```
checkpoint_path = "s3://route-databricks-sandbox-data/checkpoint/sandbox.route.dms_sample"

query = (
    kinesis
        .writeStream
        .format("delta")
        .queryName("dms_sample_output")
        .outputMode("append")
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
        .partitionBy("schema-name", "table-name")
        .toTable("sandbox.public.dms_sample")
)
```

I want to perform an aggregation over the data as it flows through my pipeline without having to re-read the data from the stream. The aggregation will be a calculation over each Kinesis shardId so it will be small and fit easily in memory.